Stream file in chunks with sftp streaming inbound adapter
I am using SFTP streaming inbound channel adapter, and it reads the entire file in one shot. It gives me an input stream that is later transformed by stream transformer I want to read the file directly from the server without downloading in chunks so that if my file is too big, it does not fill the heap. Can I do that with spring integration?
The general idea is to read files from remote file server without downloading to local or temp folder and hand it off to spring batch. Is there a way to do that with spring integration?
I want to use spring batch because if let's say app is processing a file and it dies spring batch potentially could resume from the point it failed, if I remove the entry from metadata store, I could potentially resume.

Well, that is exactly what that SFTP streaming inbound channel adapter does:
public class SftpStreamingMessageSource extends AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource<SftpClient.DirEntry> {

where that one is:
public abstract class AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource<F>
    extends AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource<InputStream> implements ManageableLifecycle {

So, the message produced by this MessageSource has an InputStream as a payload. And this one has nothing to do with the memory consumption until you do that yourself. And sounds like you do that exactly by that StreamTransformer:
/**
 * Transforms an InputStream payload to a byte[] or String (if a
 * charset is provided).
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 4.3
 *
 */
public class StreamTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {

So, if this simple appoach with loading byte array from the file InputStream does not fit into your requirements, you need to look into some other implementation where you would transform that InputStream in whatever manner you need.
Yo may look into a FileSplitter, which is able to iterate lines of the file and emit individual messages for them: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/file/splitter.html#page-title

Thank you Artem for replying, I was concerned that when it gets the input stream it holds it in memory. Lets say if my instance dies while processing file, is there a way to resume from point of failure. I tried the idempotent interceptor and it was very slow. Thats why I wanted to use spring batch. Any suggestions?

Do you mean to restart from specific line in the file? I don't think this is a reliable assumption since the file is out of application control and can be changed at any point.

Yes in a larger picture, I want to make sure I read a file and process it successfully and yes if it failed for any reason I can restart it from specific line that it failed on, given data is valid. For a different solution I used sftp inbound adapter and the local downloaded file is passed to spring batch to handle. I also set an expiration time and if that happens I remove the file from metadata store so that inbound poller can pick it up again and batch will resume cause job parameters will be same.

There is a new requirement however which forbids me to download the file to ephemeral storage. So I want to read directly from file server without downloading and seems like sftp streaming adapter can help me. Is there a way to ensure the file is successfully processed and if not could be resumed. Let me know what you think on how to achieve this. I am writing data from sftp to kafka

The files remain on the server for some time and I would generally change the extension to .done or move completed files to a different folder

I don't know how Spring Batch keeps the track of the line in the file, but with Spring Integration I indeed would try with the Idempotent Receiver after FileSplitter. Or you can implement your own splitter to keep track of the lines to skip.

I agree the idempotent interceptor works really well in keeping track of lines but it's a bit too slow. Is there a way to do that in chunks like update every 10/20 lines?

Spring batch has tables to keep track of how many records are processed based on chunks that works really well and fast, but with the streaming processor, I cannot use spring batch

Yes. That's why I suggested to implement a custom splitter which would produce a sub-set of lines as a single message instead of per line. The idempotent interceptor works against the message, so if you have fewer messages, then less meta-data hits.

Yes I agree, I will try that
